# TCombobox with gestures?

Tags: delphi, combobox, vcl, gestures

Our delphi XE3 application uses a GestureManager and some comboboxes in style csDropDownList.  Some of these comboboxes can have quite a few items in them such that they need to be scrolled occasionally.  Naturally, users expect to be able to scroll the combobox options with an up or down gesture.  Unfortunately that doesn't work because it responds to releasing the mouse button and selects the item where the mouse was.

any ideas how we could let them scroll the list with gestures?